# using web-dictaphone need to save audio to server

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I have the web-dictaphone working: https://github.com/mdn/web-dictaphone/

My goal is to have it work just like it does by default, but I want to add a save button that will save the recorded file onto the wordpress server.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?  Here is the code that executes after recording,
I imagine I need to do something with the audioURL and use something like file_put_contents() in php.  I'm not sure if I need to convert to base64 or anything?  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
  mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

  const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?','My unnamed clip');

  const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
  const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
  const audio = document.createElement('audio');
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

  clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
  audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
  deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
  deleteButton.className = 'delete';

  if(clipName === null) {
    clipLabel.textContent = 'My unnamed clip';
  } else {
    clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
  }

  clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
  clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
  clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
  soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

  audio.controls = true;
  const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
  chunks = [];
  const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.src = audioURL;
  console.log("recorder stopped");

  deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
    let evtTgt = e.target;
    evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
  }

  clipLabel.onclick = function() {
    const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
    const newClipName = prompt('Enter a new name for your sound clip?');
    if(newClipName === null) {
      clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
    } else {
      clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not needed to convert to base64, just append `blob` to an instance of the `FormData` class and send.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('attachment', blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'URL', true); // edit URL
request.onload = function() { console.log("Status: %s", request.responseText) };
request.send(formData);
```

On the backend side, receiving can be archived with `$_FILES` and `move_uploaded_file()` like a normal upload procedure.

Comment: Hi thanks.  I believe to make this work in wordpress I need to post it to an action right?  How do I set it to an action?  if I do it like this: request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'); and var whatever = 10;
      request.send('action=my_action&whatever=' + whatever); it works, but if request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');and request.send(formData); it doesn't work for me, I think because it doesn't know what action to call?  I usually post with jquery ajax not using var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); thanks

Comment: This works: request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');  request.send('action=wwd_save_audio&attachment=' + blob); but this doesn't: request.send(formData); any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I was unable to get your code to work.  I think it is because of the audio blob, something isn't right.  I updated my progress and the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291481/how-to-post-audio-blob-via-ajax-in-wordpress , thanks.

Comment: i finally got it to work, putting answer below, thanks for your help though.