# How to post audio blob via ajax in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to set up web-dictaphone to record audio then save it to the server.

My goal is to simply have them save the audio file to the wordpress server when clicking the save button.

It works and creates the blob.  However, I can't get it to post to php so I can save it.  The blob is set when the player stops, then when the save button is clicked I try to save it to the server.

```
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
    chunks = [];
    const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audio.src = audioURL;
    saveButton.onclick = function(e) {
           const ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>';
           var data = {
                action: 'wwd_save_audio',
                audio: blob,
                audioUrl: audioURL,
                processData: false,
                name: 'temp.ogg',              
                };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {                    
                console.log(response);
            });
     }
```

The blob in the console:

```
Blob {size: 11303, type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"}
size: 11303
type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"
__proto__: Blob
```

PHP (not really tested much because of issues getting it to post as a blob):

```
    function wwd_save_audio_callback()
{
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name']); 
    $audioName = uniqid() . '.ogg';
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name']);  
    $fp = fopen('../wp-content/uploads/audio/' . $audioName, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_wwd_save_audio', 'wwd_save_audio_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wwd_save_audio', 'wwd_save_audio_callback');
```

This is the error in the console that is produced if I try to attach the blob to the post like above:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at i (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at Dt (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at Dt (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at Function.S.param (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at Function.s.param (jquery-migrate-3.3.0.min.js?ver=3.3.0:2)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at Function.s.ajax (jquery-migrate-3.3.0.min.js?ver=3.3.0:2)
at Function.S.<computed> [as post] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.saveButton.onclick ((index):409)
```

If I change the above code to where the audio is just a string it posts fine,
so the error I'm getting is related to it being an audio file I believe.

```
 audio: 'blob',
```

I have also tried without success:

```
         saveButton.onclick = function(e) {
            const ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>';
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('audio', blob);
            formData.append('name', String('id', '.ogg'));
            formData.append('action', 'wwd_save_audio');

            $.ajax({
                action: 'wwd_save_audio',
                method: 'post',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: ajaxurl,
                success: function (response) {                    
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
          }
```

and it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?  I have literally been stuck on this one thing (posting an audio) for two days now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work like this:

```
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('audio', blob);
        form.append('action', 'wwd_save_audio');

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('response' + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function () {
              // handle error case here
            }
        });
```